# How to parse two different items in scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I am using scrapy 2.1 for parsing a category result page.

There are 2 different things I want to scrape from that site:

1. Category information like e.g. Title and URL
2. Product items within that category page

Number 2 works, but I am struggling on how to implement the storage of category info. My first attempt is to create another Item Class CatItem:

```
class CatItem(scrapy.Item):
    title       = scrapy.Field() # char - 
    url         = scrapy.Field() # char - 
    level       = scrapy.Field() # int - 

class ProductItem(scrapy.Item):
    title       = scrapy.Field() # char -
```

Let's parse the page:

```
def parse_item(self, response):

    # save category info
    category = CatItem()
    category['url']     = response.url
    category['title']   = response.url
    category['level']   = 1
    yield category

    # now let's parse all products within that category
    for selector in response.xpath("//article//ul/div[@data-qa-id='result-list-entry']"):

        product = ProductItem()
        product['title']          = selector.xpath(".//a/h2/text()").extract_first()
        yield product
```

My Pipeline:

```
class mysql_pipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()

    def create_connection(self):
        settings = get_project_settings()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item, spider)
        return item
```

Now here I don't know how to proceed. There is only one "item" within process_item definition.

How can I pass the category information to the store_db method as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check item type in your pipeline:

```
from your_project.items import CatItem, ProductItem

class YourPipeline(object):
...
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if isinstance(item, CatItem):
            save_category(item)
        return item
```

**UPDATE** Simple PoC code:

```
import scrapy
import csv
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class BooksPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        filename = None
        if isinstance(item, CategoryItem):
            filename = 'Categories.csv'
        elif isinstance(item, BookItem):
            filename = 'Books.csv'
        with open(filename, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['Title', 'URL'], lineterminator="\n")
            writer.writerow(item)
        return item

class BooksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "books"
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for book_url in response.xpath('//ol/li//h3/a/@href').getall():
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=response.urljoin(book_url),
                callback=self.parse_book,
            )

    def parse_book(self, response):
        category = CategoryItem()
        category['Title'] = response.xpath('//ul[@class="breadcrumb"]/li[last() - 1]/a/text()').get()
        category['URL'] = response.xpath('//ul[@class="breadcrumb"]/li[last() - 1]/a/@href').get()
        yield category

        book = BookItem()
        book['Title'] = response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()
        book['URL'] = response.url
        yield book

class BookItem(scrapy.Item):
    Title = scrapy.Field()
    URL = scrapy.Field()

class CategoryItem(scrapy.Item):
    Title = scrapy.Field()
    URL = scrapy.Field()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess(
        {
            'USER_AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36",
            'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT':100,
            'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
                '__main__.BooksPipeline': 300,
            }
        }
    )

    process.crawl(BooksSpider)
    process.start()
```

Comment: Sounds right, but does not work with my implementation. Do I have to declare CatItem anywhere in the class or pipeline? I tried:         # category or product?
        if isinstance(item, CatItem):
            print('yes')
            self.save_category(item, spider)
        else:
            print('no')
            self.store_db(item, spider) But the item is never recogniced.

Comment: Of you course you need to `import` your items to the pipeline.

Comment: I do on the top of the file: from crawler.items import DrugItem, CatItem

Comment: Any idea what could be the problem? In theory it soonds like it should work.

Comment: I get "NoneType" if I do: print(type(item).__name__) for the CatItem, while the ProductItem is correctly reported. What could that be?

Comment: Tank you. I used to have a custom image pipeline activated where item_completed somehow caused a problem. Disabled the pipeline for now and it works.